# Ubuntu :generate apk android studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, ubuntu-14.04

I am in the process of creating an android app. I use Ubuntu 14.04 as an OS and android studio 3.3 as an IDE. I want to generate the apk, i follow the following steps:

> Build > Generate signed BUndle or Apk > Apk > add the keystore.js >
>   choose V1 and V2 and release > finish

The gradle file contains the following information

> ```
> keyAlias 'key'
>             keyPassword '1234565789'
>             storeFile file('/home/development/Android/KeyStore/app.jks')
>             storePassword '123456789'
> ```

After that, the following error appear when i click my apk:

> The file
>   '/home/development/Android/App/app/release/app-release.apk' is not
>   marked as executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an
>   untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run.  For more details, read
>   about the executable bit.

Comment: Why do you required to open APK?

Comment: How can i test my app ?

Comment: You do need to install in a device

Comment: could you please tell me how ??

Comment: Copy the apk into your mobile and install from there

Comment: don't select v2 select only v1